# TISE solutions should be combinations of eigenstates. Why this is not the case?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

I would really appreciate some help with a question I have about the TISE (Sch. tipe independent equation). This is a linear equation and linear combination of the solution should be solution too. The problem is that for the free particle, which solution can be written like exp[-ikx], a linear combination using gaussian coefficient is not anymore a solution (we should get a wave pocket this way). Of course taking a combination considering the temporal dependence give a solution to the TDSE. My question is why that does not apply in the TISE case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time independent Schrodinger equation is not a single differential equation, rather it is a family of differential equations parameterized by the energy $E$.
$$\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi + V\psi = E\psi$$
A solution to the TISE for one value of $E$ won't be a solution to the TISE for a different $E$, and so an arbitrary sum of solutions for different energies won't be a solution for any energy.